# ASP.NET CSS file path resolution confusion

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. Inside the master page I specify the header code which contains `css` and `javascript` file declarations and use `runat=server` attribute. Now for javascript files I have to specify the `ResolveUrl` method in the master page otherwise they won't get executed by the browser but `CSS` files will work fine without `ResolveUrl` method.

I thought `CSS` files were also executed on the client side and don't understand why they do not require using `ResolveUrl` method.

Why do `JavaScript` files require the `ResolveUrl` method, but `CSS` files do not?

Here is an excrept from the master page head code:

```
<head runat="server">

<!-- Basic Page Needs
    ================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home </title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    ================================================== -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- CSS
    ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/skeleton.css" class="responsive">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/color/orange.css" class="color">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/colorbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/sequence.css">
<!-- Fonts
    ================================================== -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/flexslider-min.js") %>"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/selectnav.min.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/ui.totop.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/easing.1.3.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jcarousel.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/jflickrfeed.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/twitter/tweet.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/custom.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/sequence-min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/quicksand.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/js/colorbox.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the `<head>` that declares a `.js` and a `.css` file?

Comment: It seems that Web Forms process the link elements that exist in the `<head runat="server">`, if outside you need to use the `ResolveUrl` function. But I couldn't find a reference for this feature and why it applies only in css files.